# HSQLDB: Prioritize Select queries over Insert queries

Tags: mysql, hsqldb

I'm having multiple `HSQL` database connections active at the same time. Most of them are inserting data and a few of them are reading data.

Is there a way to "pause" the insert queries while a select query is running?

I read that in MySQL there used to be such a feature called `INSERT DELAYED` which did exactly that but is now deprecated.

My current solution is that when I request a `SELECT` query to let the `INSERT` query thread sleep for a fixed amount of time. This seems to be a great workaround for this issue since the `SELECT` query is now very fast. I'd still prefere to have a built in solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the default transaction isolation model, LOCKS, you can lock the tables that are inserted into before you perform the SELECT statement. Committing the transaction after the SELECT unlocks the tables.